# How i can see stacktrace for crash of my app in play market?

Tags: android

In play market console I see just statistic how many times my app was crashed. How I can see stack for this crashes?

Should I do some additional steps in adding my app to play market. I just added APK.

**what I see on playmarket**

[image: what I see on playmarket]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the GooglePlay Console, on the left menu in **Quality** (*Качество*) section, select **Android Vitals** -> **Crashes and ANRs** (*Сбои и ошибки ANR* in Russian)

[image: Crashes and ANRs (ru)]

It will give you detailed information about crashes.

But to see the full stack trace first you need to *upload ReTrace mapping file* (*Файл сопоставления ReTrace*) - you can find this option in "App Bundle Explorer" when selecting your APK version.

[image: ReTrace upload field]

Otherwise you'll see an obfuscated stack trace.

Probably you already have this file (*mapping.txt*) among the generated files of the project. If not, read here how to generate this file: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633